# babylon.js meshes get same material

Tags: javascript, blender, babylonjs

I'm using BabylonJS V3 with Blender 2.79 to create product visualizations. Many times, it is necessary to define more complex shaders in the JS code. I'm using lines like

```js
scene.meshes[1].material.emissiveColor = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 0, 0);
```

to define the shaders after export. Usually every mesh can get it's own shader this way. Unfortunately in one case, the shader of multiple meshes is overwritten. Did someone have a similar problem?
All meshes are named individually, they all have a basic (individual) shader from blender. They don't share any datablocks, no instancing or duplication was done. I'm thankful for every hint.

## Edit

It seems, the error occurs with the new version (3.0), updating to 3.1 fixes the problem, but introduces errors with the arc-rotate camera. As soon as you click on the canvas, to rotate the view, you can't release the mouse anymore. Are the latest stable releases buggy?

## Edit 2

After some in depth trouble shooting we came to the conclusion, that the 3.0 and 3.1 versions and/or their exporter plugins are faulty. Even in the simplest testscenes, this error occurs. Alongside other problems, like broken cameras and displaced geometry.

Comment: Could you share the complete scene? http://playground.babylonjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that by default materials are shared for performance reason. So this is probably not a bug but a feature.
If you want to change the material for a single mesh you will first need to clone it